# Query data from multiple tables in SQL Server using C#

Tags: multiple-tables, sql-server-2014

I have 3 database tables:

- `tbl_member` (member_name, address, card_no)
- `tbl_card` (card_no, card_type, exp_date)
- `tbl_member_type` (memtype_id, memtype_name, dsc_rate) / (memtype_Id = card_type)

I want to make a query to get `member_name`, `exp_date`, `memtype_name`, `dsc_rate` when I input `card_no`.

I tried

```
Select 
    memtype_name, dsc_rate 
from 
    tbl_member_type 
Where 
    mem_typeId = (Select C.card_type 
                  from tbl_card C 
                  Where C.card_no = '123456') 
UNION ALL

Select 
    M.member_name, C.exp_date 
From 
    tbl_member M, tbl_card C 
Where 
    M.member_cardno = '123456'
```

Another one is

```
SELECT member_name FROM tbl_member WHERE member_cardno='123456'
UNION
SELECT exp_date FROM tbl_card WHERE card_no='123456'
UNION
SELECT dsc_rate, memtype_name 
FROM tbl_member_type 
WHERE mem_typeId = (SELECT card_type 
                    FROM tbl_card 
                    WHERE card_no='123456')
```

Comment: sorry for my unclear question. Internet connection is bad at my place and I can not make question well .

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: SELECT dsc_rate, memtype_name FROM tbl_member_type WHERE mem_typeId= ( SELECT card_type from tbl_card WHERE card_no='123456') 
  UNION
 Select M.member_name, C.exp_date From tbl_member M JOIN tbl_card C ON M.member_cardno=C.card_no WHERE C.card_no='123456'

Comment: only single query give me result, but it is not work with UNION , can I use PRODUCT keyword in this case ?

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.